# One line method invocation with C# 6 for an awaitable method?

Tags: c#, mono, async-await, c#-6.0

In Jon Skeet's C# 6 post entitled [Clean Event Handlers Invocation with C# 6](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/) he shows how you can now write

```
public void OnFoo()
{
    Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

instead of

```
public void OnFoo()
{
    EventHandler handler = Foo;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }   
}
```

Is there any way to do a one-liner like that if we're talking about an awaitable method? If I try

```
await Foo?.Invoke();
```

I get the following compile error:

> The awaiter type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter?` must have suitable `IsCompleted` and `GetResult` members (CS4011).

Note: I am using Mono (Xamarin Studio for OSX v5.9.5), so the compiler results can vary from what one might get using Visual Studio.

Comment: Unrelated, you should code in a VM of windows for .net stuff. Much better experience on OSX.    Sorry off topic. I don't think you can await since it doesn't have the reporting status methods.

Comment: I do both and I find working in OSX to be much better than working in a VM (even with key remapping, etc). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I tried reproducing this in Visual Studio and didn't get a compiler error, but I got a warning about a possible null exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@i3arnon Has a good solution, however this is another way that you *could* do it that wouldn't require adding a field or property.

```
await (Foo?.Invoke() ?? Task.CompletedTask);
```

or if `Task<T>`

```
var i = await (Foo?.Invoke() ?? Task.FromResult<T>(default(T)))
```

Comment: What namespace or .NET version is `Task.CompletedTask` in? I don't have that property/field.

Comment: @valdetero .NET 4.6. As of today it's not yet available in Mono unfortunately. Task.FromResult works though.

Comment: @NateCook ah, that makes sense. Also wasn't in my PCL profile 259.

Answer (score 4):

Not if you're trying to use the null propagation operator (i.e. `?.`).

When you use this operator the result must be of a nullable type, since it may or may not invoke the method (depending on whether `Foo` is `null`). Reference types are nullable but value types (structs) are not so for them this operator returns `Nullable<T>` (`T?`).

When you `await` something it compiles into calling `GetAwaiter` on that awaitable (usually a `Task`) and getting an awaiter (usually `TaskAwaiter`) that has `IsCompleted`, `GetResult` and `OnCompleted`. If a type doesn't have all these then it's not awaitable and you can't await it.

So in your case, you call `Foo?.Invoke()` and get back a `Nullable<TaskAwaiter>` (i.e. `TaskAwaiter?`) since `TaskAwaiter` is a struct and `TaskAwaiter?` doesn't have the required methods (unlike `TaskAwaiter` itself) it can't be awaited (it wouldn't have been possible even if `TaskAwaiter` was a class since you can't await a `null`).

However, you can simply initialize `Foo` with an efficient dummy registration so it wouldn't ever be `null` and you wouldn't need to check it:

```
Func<Task> Foo = () => Task.CompletedTask;

public void OnFoo()
{
    await Foo();
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation of _why_ the one-liner in the question doesn't compile.

Comment: What namespace or .NET version is `Task.CompletedTask` in? I don't have that property/field.

Comment: @valdetero It's on .Net 4.6.